# NAS causing Internet Time Outs on other computers

Tags: networking, lan, nas, wireshark, synology

Yesterday I installed a new Synology DS715 NAS server. Since then the internet connection on all other LAN connected PCs encounter disconnects. This is most noticable when playing online games, which would result in a disconnect from the game. When the DS715 is turned off the game runs perfectly, and when it's turned back on again the disconnects usually start within a couple of minutes.

The things I've tried to fix the problem include:

- Disabling UPnP in the router.
- Disabling all applications in the Package Center, like the Mediaserver etc.
- Disabling the QuickConnect and external access.
- Connecting the DS715 directly to the router, and using only 1 of the LAN ports.
- Using a Static IP address.

To debug the problem I used WireShark in combination with a continuous ping to Google. Before making any changes I got a lot of TCP errors right when the Request Timed Out occurred, as can be seen in the screenshot below.

[WireShark before any changes, during a Request Timed Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlzSx.png)

After I made these changes, the connection seemed to be a lot more stable, but disconnects from the game still occur. And again, it runs perfectly with the DS715 turned off.

The WireShark during such a disconnect, after the changes, still shows the TCP Retransimission error. A screenshot can be seen below.

[WireShark after changes, during a disconnect from the game (and Request Timed Out as well)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWMAd.png)

I hope someone can help me fix the problem, as I'm really out of things to try.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
I've sent the DS715 back and I've bought a Qnap TS253 Pro instead. It's been running for a few days now, without any problems whatsoever.

Comment: Does the Synology include a DHCP server, that has not been switched off?

Comment: The DHCP server has always been turned off.

Comment: Did you check for IP address collisions?

Comment: Yes, DHCP (router) only provides IPs above 10, and the NAS is configured on 2. No other static devices use 2.

Comment: Synology NAS's have been hacked.  I wonder if you are running an old version of the firmware and has been compromised and is part of a DoS or something.   It may be worthwhile factory resetting it and then installing the latest firmware, and ensuring its firewalled as best you can.

Comment: @davidgo I bought it yesterday and it's been running the latest firmware since the beginning.

Comment: "I think we have finally fixed this issue on our DS1515+. When I turned off the automatic time synchronization in Regional Options and set it to manual, the network interrupts stopped. I tested this again this morning and within 5 minutes of the synchronized time being turned on, the network showed 3-5 segments of ping timeouts. This seems to be the fix for us, hope this helps others."

Answer (score 0):

As life happens, I ran into this exact problem today. The issue turned out to be that Dropbox was syncing a very large amount of data and taking all the available bandwidth on an ADSL connection (with, I imagine, about 600kbit upload).

Going in to the Synology box and capping the speed of sync fixed my problems.